# Use getclicky to have most views nodes on home page

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I have installed the getclicky module and I can see the stats most views content.
How can I add that info in a view on my home page and list the top 10 nodes?
I cannot use the Statistics module.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using [google analytics reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports). and added the top page view in my homepage.